# Busqueda avanzada y consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas a todos, tengo un problema a la hora de realizar una consulta, ya que no me devuelve el resultado deseado.

Las condiciones para las consulta las marca el usuario con un formulario similar a este:
[image: Formulario]

Y esto es el esquema de las tablas:
[image: Esquema de las tablas]

y finalmente, la consulta que estoy intentando usar:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT m.Nombre_IUPAC,m.Nombre_Tradicional, r.Ruta, m.Imagen_Molecula, m.Codigo_Producto, m.idMolecula
FROM molecula as m 
join ruta as r
ON r.idRuta=m.Ruta_Imagen_Molecula
join molecula_has_organismo_productor as mo
on m.idMolecula=mo.Molecula_idMolecula
join organismo_productor as op
on op.idOrganismo_Productor=mo.Organismo_Productor_idOrganismo_Productor
left join carbono as c
on c.Molecula_idMolecula=m.idMolecula
    left join tipo_carbono as tc
    on tc.idTipo_Carbono=c.Tipo_Carbono_idTipo_Carbono
join actividad_biologica_has_molecula as abm
on abm.molecula_idMolecula=m.idMolecula
    join actividad_biologica as ab
    on ab.idActividad_Biologica=abm.Actividad_Biologica_idActividad_Biologica
        where m.Nombre_Tradicional like ''
        or m.Nombre_IUPAC like ''
        or m.Codigo_Producto like ''
        or op.Nombre like ''
        or m.Peso_Molecular BETWEEN '' AND ''
        or tc.Carbono = ''
        or c.Desplazamiento BETWEEN '' AND ''
        or ab.Nombre in ('Ipsum','Flamatoria')
            group by m.idMolecula
            having count(1)=2
```

El problema con toda esta consulta es que hay registros que no me salen cuando quiero filtrar las opciones de actividad biologica, pero me aparecen si quito la relacion que tengo planteada con organismo productor. Sere franco, no se manejar los join con tantas tablas, y el problema seguramente estara ahi.

Comment: Sin conocer la "lógica de negocios" es muy difícil evaluar si una consulta es correcta, tal vez serviría si agregás un ejemplo aunque sea mínimo de los valores de cada tabla y particularmente un ejemplo que falle tal como lo mencionás

Comment: No puedo poner mas imagenes porque necesito 10 de reputacion. La consulta la he comprobado sin el resto de joins y funciona perfectamente (me refiero a la que trabaja solo con la de actividad biologica), pero en esta consulta no me funciona correctamente. Solo me sale uno de los dos registros que deberian salir. Y como indico arriba, si quito los joins que relacionan con las tablas de "organismo productor", la consulta funciona. Pero necesito esa relacion tambien.

Comment: Estas seguro que el "nombre" que usas en el WHERE es de la tabla "actividad_biologica_has_molecula" y no de la tabla "actividad biologica"?

Comment: Mirá, la respuesta de @ Zartch es bastante explicativa, vos estas haciendo en todo los casos INNERs JOINs, por lo que si o si cada tabla debe tener registros con el mismo id. Lo que tenes que hacer es encontrar el JOIN que te "quita" datos, comentando uno por uno, y una vez encontrado, entender si es un problema de datos (la tabla detalle no tiene al menos un registro con el ID de la maestra) o simplemente corresponde hacer un LEFT JOIN por que es "logico" que en algunos casos no exista información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, creo que ya entendí lo que buscas, prueba añadiendo un DISTINCT al filtro del COUNT, para que se asegure de que todas las opciones del IN coincidan.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Nombre_IUPAC,m.Nombre_Tradicional, m.idMolecula, op.Nombre as OrgProductor, tc.Carbono as Carbonom, ab.Nombre as ActividadBiologica
FROM molecula as m 
left join ruta as r ON r.idRuta=m.Ruta_Imagen_Molecula
left join molecula_has_organismo_productor as mo on m.idMolecula=mo.Molecula_idMolecula
left join organismo_productor as op on op.idOrganismo_Productor=mo.Organismo_Productor_idOrganismo_Productor
left join carbono as c on c.Molecula_idMolecula=m.idMolecula
left join tipo_carbono as tc on tc.idTipo_Carbono=c.Tipo_Carbono_idTipo_Carbono
left join actividad_biologica_has_molecula as abm on abm.molecula_idMolecula = m.idMolecula
left join actividad_biologica as ab on abm.Actividad_Biologica_idActividad_Biologica = ab.idActividad_Biologica
WHERE ab.Nombre IN ('Ipsum', 'Flamatoria')
GROUP BY m.idMolecula
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ab.Nombre) = 2
```

Comment: La verdad, no entiendo porque, pero funciona :D Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No pruebo probar nada debido a la dificultad de las tablas, pero yo también creo que tus problemas están en los joins.

Normalmente el join que te interesa hacer es INNER JOIN Que son los campos que coinciden en las dos tablas. Veo algunos left join, que si no tienes claro lo que son, probablemente este ahí el problema (JOIN = INNER JOIN, el 'inner se pone a modo clarificador')

Te recomiendo echarle un ojo a este esquema de diagramas de Venn que creo que clarifica bastante que datos devuelven los diferentes tipos de JOINS.

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/b0/3d/67/b03d6794fb787492bea0f41a8144a37d.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Buenas, creo que ya entendí lo que buscas, prueba añadiendo un DISTINCT al filtro del COUNT, para que se asegure de que todas las opciones del IN coincidan.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT m.Nombre_IUPAC,m.Nombre_Tradicional, m.idMolecula, op.Nombre as OrgProductor, tc.Carbono as Carbonom, ab.Nombre as ActividadBiologica
FROM molecula as m 
left join ruta as r ON r.idRuta=m.Ruta_Imagen_Molecula
left join molecula_has_organismo_productor as mo on m.idMolecula=mo.Molecula_idMolecula
left join organismo_productor as op on op.idOrganismo_Productor=mo.Organismo_Productor_idOrganismo_Productor
left join carbono as c on c.Molecula_idMolecula=m.idMolecula
left join tipo_carbono as tc on tc.idTipo_Carbono=c.Tipo_Carbono_idTipo_Carbono
left join actividad_biologica_has_molecula as abm on abm.molecula_idMolecula = m.idMolecula
left join actividad_biologica as ab on abm.Actividad_Biologica_idActividad_Biologica = ab.idActividad_Biologica
WHERE ab.Nombre IN ('Ipsum', 'Flamatoria')
GROUP BY m.idMolecula
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ab.Nombre) = 2
```